# MVC 5 and Oauth 2.0: when changing browsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, token

I have an MVC app that authenticates users with their microsoft accounts using the default options set for Oauth 2.0 on an MVC 5 app. When logging in for the first time, let's say on firefox using my account credentials, it asks for associating a username to this email and it is working perfectly; the user infos are stored in the database and so on. The problem is when I change browsers and use the same email to log in, I am then asked again to associate another username to the same email account and end up having two different usernames for the same Microsoft account. 
I understand that Oauth2 is now supposed to provide identification and authorization and that it relies on grants. Thus, I think the problem could be caused by these lines since cookies are proper to each browser:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

Then, is there a way to making the user unique regardless of the browser? I would appreciate any relevant suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.